# What is the best way to work with many interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a situation where I have have a lot of model classes (~1000) which implement any number of 5 interfaces. So I have classes which implement one and others which implement four or five.

This means I can have any permutation of those five interfaces. In the classical model, I would have to implement 32-5 = 27 "meta interfaces" which "join" the interfaces in a bundle. Often, this is not a problem because `IB` usually extends `IA`, etc. but in my case, the five interfaces are orthogonal/independent.

In my framework code, I have methods which need instances that have any number of these interfaces implemented. So lets assume that we have the class `X` and the interfaces `IA`, `IB`, `IC`, `ID` and `IE`. `X` implements `IA`, `ID` and `IE`.

The situation gets worse because some of these interfaces have [formal type parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html).

I now have two options:

1. I could define an interface `IADE` (or rather `IPersistable_MasterSlaveCapable_XmlIdentifierProvider`; underscores just for your reading pleasure)
2. I could define a generic type as `<T extends IPersistable & IMasterSlaveCapable & IXmlIdentifierProvider>` which would give me a handy way to mix & match interfaces as I need them.
3. I could use code like this: `IA a = ...; ID d = (ID)a; IE e = (IE)e` and then use the local variable with the correct type to call methods even though all three work on the same instance. Or use a cast in every second method call.

The first solution means that I get a lot of empty interfaces with very unreadable names.

The second uses a kind of "ad-hoc" typing. And Oracle's `javac` sometimes stumbles over them while Eclipse gets it right.

The last solution uses casts. Nuff said.

Questions:

1. Is there a better solution for mixing any number of interfaces?
2. Are there any reasons to avoid the temporary types which solution #2 offers me (except for shortcomings in Oracle's `javac`)?

Note: I'm aware that writing code which doesn't compile with Oracle's `javac` is a risk. We know that we can handle this risk.

**[Edit]** There seems to be some confusion what I try to attempt here. My model instances can have one of these traits:

- They can be "master slave capable" (think cloning)
- They can have an XML identifier
- They might support tree operations (parent/child)
- They might support revisions
- etc. (yes, the model is even more complex than that)

Now I have support code which operates on trees. An extensions of trees are trees with revisions. But I also have revisions without trees.

When I'm in the code to add a child in the revision tree manager, I know that each instance must implement `ITtree` and `IRevisionable` but there is no common interface for both because these are completely independent concerns.

But in the implementation, I need to call methods on the nodes of the tree:

```
public void addChild( T parent, T child ) {
    T newRev = parent.createNewRevision();
    newRev.addChild( foo );
    ... possibly more method calls to other interfaces ...
}
```

If `createNewRevision` is in the interface `IRevisionable` and `addChild` is in the interface `ITree`, what are my options to define `T`?

Note: Assume that I have several other interfaces which work in a similar way: There are many places where they are independent but some code needs to see a mix of them. `IRevisionableTree` is not a solution but another problem.

I could cast the type for each call but that seems clumsy. Creating all permutations of interfaces would be boring and there seems no reasonable pattern to compress the huge interface names. Generics offer a nice way out:

```
public
<T extends IRevisionable & ITree>
void addChild( T parent, T child ) { ... }
```

This doesn't always work with Oracle's `javac` but it seems compact and useful. Any other options/comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Loosely coupled capabilities** might be interesting. An [example here](http://netbeans.dzone.com/loosely-coupled-reloadable-capabilities).
It is an entirely different approach; decoupling things instead of typing.
Basically interfaces are hidden, implemented as delegating field.

```
IA ia = x.lookupCapability(IA.class);
if (ia != null) {
    ia.a();
}
```

It fits here, as with many interfaces the wish to decouple rises, and you can more easily combine cases of interdepending interfaces (`if (ia != null && ib != null) ...`).

Comment: +1 This looks like Eclipse's IAdaptable (http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/what-is-iadaptable/)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a method (semicode)

```
void doSomething(IA & ID & IE thing);
```

then my main concern is: Couldn't `doSomething` be better tailored? Might it be better to split up the functionality? Or are the interfaces itself badly tailored?

I have stumbled over similar things several times and each time it proved to be better to take *big* step backward and rethink the complete partitioning of the logic - not only due to the stuff you mentioned but also due to other concerns.

Since you formulated your question very abstractly (i.e. without a sensible example) I cannot tell you if that's advisable in your case also.

Comment: I have an interface for `Tree` which gets `IA` but in an implementation, I know that at this stage, `thing` must also implement `ID` and `IE`. What abstract type should I use for `thing`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Abstract stuff like _Tree_, _IA_ and _thing_ will not help - this is to far away in order to really _understand_ your problem domain and to distil new, useful abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid all "artificial" interfaces/types that attempt to represent combinations. It's just bad design... what happens if you add 5 more interfaces? The number of combinations explodes.

It seems you want to know if some instance implements some interface(s). Reasonable options are:

- use `instanceof` - there is no shame
- use reflection to discover the interfaces via `object.getClass().getInterfaces()` - you may be able to write some general code to process stuff
- use reflection to discover the methods via `object.getClass().getMethods()` and just invoke those that match a known list of methods of your interfaces (this approach means you don't have to care what it implements - sounds simple and therefore sounds like a good idea)

You've given us no context as to exactly *why* you want to know, so it's hard to say what the "best" approach is.

#### Edited

OK. Since your extra info was added it's starting to make sense. The best approach here is to use the a callback: Instead of passing in a parent object, pass in an interface that accepts a "child".

It's a simplistic version of the visitor pattern. Your calling code knows what it is calling with and how it can handle a child, but the code that navigates around and/or decides to add a child doesn't have context of the caller.

Your code would look something like this (caveat: May not compile; I just typed it in):

```
public interface Parent<T> {
    void accept(T child);
}

// Central code - I assume the parent is passed in somewhere earlier
public void process(Parent<T> parent) {
    // some logic that decides to add a child
    addChild(parent, child);
}

public void addChild(Parent<T> parent, T child ) {
    parent.accept(child);
}

// Calling code
final IRevisionable revisionable = ...;
someServer.process(new Parent<T> {
    void accept(T child) {
        T newRev = revisionable.createNewRevision();
        newRev.addChild(child);
    }
}
```

You may have to juggle things around, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: My situation is the opposite: I know that at certain point in code, `foo` must implement `IA`, `ID` and `IE` (otherwise, it couldn't get that far). Now I need to call methods in all three interfaces. What type should `foo` get?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (foo instanceof IA && foo instanceof ID && foo instanceof IE) { foo.doSomething();}`? Can you give more business context? Your questions are all about a particular approach - what is it you are trying to do (in plain English - not code)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually solution 1 is a good solution, but you should find a better naming.

What actually would you name a class that implements the `IPersistable_MasterSlaveCapable_XmlIdentifierProvider` interface? If you follow good naming convention, it should have a meaningful name originating from a model entity. You can give the interface the same name prefixed with `I`.

I don't find it a disadvantage to have many interfaces, because like that you can write mock implementations for testing purposes.

Comment: The classes which implement this interface are called `OrgUnit`, `User`, `ClientInfo`, ...

Comment: so you name your interfaces: `IOrgUnit`, `IUser`, `IClientInfo`, and so on.
That way you can have mock implementations like `OrgUnitMock`, `UserMock` and `ClientInfoMock` implementing those interfaces.

Comment: That would give me 1000 interfaces.

Comment: you already have 1000 classes. Usually defining an interface for each class is a good design strategy to simplefy testing by mocking the class

Answer (score 0):

> My situation is the opposite: I know that at certain point in code,
>   foo must implement IA, ID and IE (otherwise, it couldn't get that
>   far). Now I need to call methods in all three interfaces. What type
>   should foo get?

Are you able to bypass the problem entirely by passing (for example) three objects? So instead of:

```
doSomethingWithFoo(WhatGoesHere foo);
```

you do:

```
doSomethingWithFoo(IA foo, ID foo, IE foo);
```

Or, you could create a proxy that implements all interfaces, but allows you to disable certain interfaces (i.e. calling the 'wrong' interface causes an UnsupportedOperationException).

One final wild idea - it *might* be possible to create Dynamic Proxies for the appropriate interfaces, that delegate to your actual object.

Comment: I don't like the "one instance becomes three" because eventually, someone will assign a new value to one of the "foo"s or call the method with more than one instance. Also dynamic proxies are too slow.